# How to take the index of the nearest centroid as a feature?

Tags: k-means, feature-engineering

To create additional features for a dataset I have conducted a cluster analysis and assigned a feature to a data set for cluster membership:

```
# Determine number of clusters
wss <- (nrow(train.n)-1)*sum(apply(train.n[,2:74],2,var))
for (i in 2:74) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(train.n[,2:74],
                                     centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:74, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares")

# K-Means Cluster Analysis
# append cluster assignment
fit   <- kmeans(train.n, 6)
train <- data.frame(train, fit$cluster)
    fit   <- kmeans(test.n, 6)
    test  <- data.frame(test, fit2$cluster)
```

But [this](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/294-fall09/lectures/feature/slides.pdf) presentation from Berkeley suggests to use "the index of the nearest centroid" as a feature. I'm a little unclear on this.

Could someone explain how this is different and give an example, either based on my example R code or in another language?

Comment: Bare requests for implementation in a specific language (in place of more general explanation) are generally seen as off topic here. Please see the [help/on-topic]; you may be able to modify your question to be more clearly on topic for our site.

Comment: @Glen_b I didn't think it was a "bare" request -- I showed what I'm already doing and provided a presentation covering a variation of what I'm doing and asked how to do the variation. I'll broaden the question to be language independent.

Comment: By "bare" I mean "without any question to answer that relates to a statistical issue" / "dealing only with coding aspects"

Comment: @Glen_b Well then I'd respectfully say that you were off base. I clearly inquired into a statistical issue -- I explained my understanding and use of k-means cluster analysis for modeling latent variables, presented a statistical technique from Berkeley, and asked for an explanation of how or if it was different from what I was doing. I'd much rather ask a question on StackOverflow where I have > 10x more reputation points, but this was clearly a statistical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to interpret the author's intent from slides, but I would generally interpret the cluster membership described as a categorical variable.

From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html), it appears that `kmeans$cluster` has integers corresponding to cluster. You're right that this *is* interpretable as an index, but many software implementations of learning algorithms will treat this as a numeric value by default. Some, like the example below, require transforming them into several boolean variables.

In this case, each boolean would describe whether the datum is nearest to a particular cluster. (I believe R—or at least some packages—has a means of treating integer columns as categories, but I don't use it enough to speak with authority.)

Here's an example in python using the iris dataset and [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/):

```
import numpy as np, sklearn
from sklearn import datasets, preprocessing
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
clusters = np.argmin(kmeans.fit_transform(X), axis = 1) # fit_transform transforms X into cluster distance space; argmin is the cluster with minimum distance
print clusters
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
clustersAsBoolean = enc.fit_transform(clusters.reshape(-1,1))
print clustersAsBoolean
```

The first print statement will show recognizable cluster indices:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2]
```

The second (shortened):

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 1.,  0.,  0.] 
     ...
     [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Oh, ok great. So, it sounds like what that author was (presumably) doing was the same as what I was doing and what you're doing -- just saying which cluster an observation belongs to. I thought the "index" might imply some sort of different information, so this makes me feel more confident.